# Swift FacebookSDK Graphrequest Completion Handler not called

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-sdk-4.0, fbsdk

if i implement the following function directly on the viewController everything works fine. (this is not complete, but it works for the picture)

```
func getFBData() {

if((FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()) != nil){
    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, first_name, last_name, picture"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
        if (error == nil){
            let email = result.valueForKey("email") as? String
            let fbid = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
            let fname = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! String
            let lname = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! String
            let facebookProfileUrl = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(fbid)/picture?type=large"

            let url = NSURL(string: facebookProfileUrl)

            if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!) {
                self.imgProfile.image = UIImage(data: data)
            }
        }
    })
}
```

}

But instead i tried to keep all the facebook related stuff separated in a **FacebookController.swift** class.

```
class func getUserData() -> [String: String] {

    var dict: [String: String]?
    let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken()
    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, email, name, first_name, last_name, picture"])

    if((token) != nil) {
        graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {

                let fbid = result.valueForKey("id") as! String
                let name = result.valueForKey("name") as? String
                let fname = result.valueForKey("first_name") as! String
                let lname = result.valueForKey("last_name") as! String
                let email = result.valueForKey("email") as? String
                let pictureURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/\(fbid)/picture?type=large"

                dict = ["id": fbid, "name": name!, "fname": fname, "lname": lname, "email": email!, "picture": pictureURL]
                print(dict)
            } else {
                print("ok")
                print("\(error)")
            }

        })

    }
    return dict!
}
```

The User is logged in and all the permissions are granted, but when i try to call `FacebookController()`.`getUserData()` it returns dict, which is nil. I already figured that this is because the **completionHandler** of the `graphRequest` never gets called.

Can anybody help?

Comment: I think you might need to make that an instance method and instantiate the class so you can maintain a reference. I'm thinking you call it and it executes but since it's not retained it's released.

Comment: thank you, i tried that. now i'm keeping a reference to a FacebookController and i changed the class methods to instance methods. unfortunately i'm still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: it seems to be somehow connected to the return dict! statement. if don't return anything and delete -> [String:String] and the return statement and just do print(dict!) at the end of the function, it works fine.

Comment: That's happening b/c your dict is out of scope - the return is executing before the closure is completing.

Comment: Thank you so much already! I finally figured it out. The graph request completion handler seems to be asynchronous and it is not possible to get a return value from there. So it seems that dict was not set by the completion handler by the time that i tried to return it. I needed to call another function (which receives the dict as a parameter and returns it) from the completion handler to ensure that the value will not be returned until the completion handler finished.